# How do you used the word "assign" in mathematics-function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, terminology

This is not a mathematical relation problem, but more about English in maths.

By definition, the function maps each element in the domain to exactly one element in the codomain. From Wikipedia, the word "assign to" also indicates from domain to codomain *(there is a directional meaning in assign)*.

[wiki-function](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Function_(mathematics))

This capture reminds me of once I argue with the lecturer about the "assign", he told me that you have to say the function assigns unique y to x.
[image]

[capture link](https://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi2/sec_intro-functions.html#:%7E:text=A%20function%20is%20a%20rule%20that%20assigns%20each%20element%20of,second%20set%2C%20called%20the%20codomain%20.)

What is the correct way to use the word assign in mathematical function?

Comment: For functions, you have already explained what the correct use of the word "assign" is. But you can also use the word in different mathematical contexts, in both directions (and not only from domain to codomain). For a similar question  see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3798807/what-meaning-should-i-assign-to-assign).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What meaning should I assign to "assign"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3798807/what-meaning-should-i-assign-to-assign)

Comment: @DietrichBurde so one should say assign $y$ to $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes actually you can use assign it is pointed classically for a function $f$ from domain $D$ to codomain $D'$, with $x$ the variable

$$ f : x \to f(x) $$

The assignement takes form in the arrow above.
And can be used reversely as explained in precisions.

**Precisions**

1. As said in your text, a function to be called *a function* must, for each element of $D$ the domain, assign a unique value $f(x)$.
2. Reciprocally if you take an element of domain $D'$, let's say $y$ you may find $0$, one or several elements $x$, sum up by the set $f^{-1}(y)$ in the domain $D$ such as $\forall x \in f^{-1}(y), \ f(x)=y$.

**Conclusion**

The word assign is perfectly adequate for speaking of function as the precisions above are fulfilled.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes thanks